# A "central place" where to definitely set the SSL certificate variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, global-variables

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to have a "central place" where to definitely set the SSL certificate to use inside my application.

Almost everywhere in code I have HTTPS requests like this

```
e = Typhoeus::Request.get("https://example.com/action",
  :ssl_cacert => "ca_file.cer",
  :ssl_cert => "acert.crt",
  :ssl_key => "akey.key",
  [...]
end
```

So, in order to specify a SSL certificate for all my request, I would like to set a global variable (I heard that global variable can be dangerous...) or something like that in a safe way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a SSL helper class, and use that (I'd put it in lib, but that's mostly just user preference):

```
class MySSL
    SSL_DEFAULTS = {
        :ssl_cacert => 'ca_cert.cer',
        :ssl_cery => 'acert.crt',
        :ssl_key => 'akey.key'
    }

    def self.get(uri, options = {})
        options.reverse_merge!(SSL_DEFAULTS)
        Typhoeus::Request.get(uri, options)
    end

    # And so forth for post, etc.
end
```

Where [reverse_merge!](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/ReverseMerge/reverse_merge) is a convenient Rails extension to give default options for a hash (if the original hash has those keys already, they won't be overwritten).  You avoid setting a global variable, too, by using a class constant.  And in the rest of your code, you're able to call

```
MySSL.get('https://example.com/action')
```

or

```
MySSL.get('https://example.com/action', :other => :options)
```

which are a lot cleaner, in comparison.

Hope this helps!

Comment: For security reasons, for example, is it recommended to 'freeze' o doing something else on the class constant 'SSL_DEFAULTS'?

Comment: @user502052  Might be a good idea.  It wouldn't be for security - you're not letting foreign code run in your app, I hope, so you're the only one who could change the values - but it would keep _you_ from accidentally changing things.  Especially since `SSL_DEFAULTS[:key] = 'hullabaloo'` won't raise a warning, even though `SSL_DEFAULTS` is a constant.  Cheers!

Comment: Another "fast" question about this topic: Is it advisable to state the SSL global variable in the 'environment.rb' file, in a '/initializer/' file or in an '/environments/' file instead of do that inside the class (as you did)? If so, how to do that to make the variable accessible in all the application?

Comment: @user502052  For the most part, I'd say it's just personal preference.  If you want different SSL defaults per environment, though, the environments/whatever.rb file is absolutely the way to go - a constant declared in those files should be accessible anywhere in your app.  I imagine constants in initializers/ work the same way, though I don't know for sure (I've only used them for class extensions).  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_CERT_STORE` methods `#add_file` and `#add_path` to set it on the default cert store; this will get picked up by pretty much everything that doesn't override it, in particular Net::HTTP. I'm not sure about Typhoeus, but it should work as long as it doesn't change it.